# A chain is only as strong as its weakest link

Tags: traduction, locutions

Y-a-t-il une locution française equivalent au *a chain is only as strong as its weakest link* ? [Linguee propose des traduction mot-par-mot](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/a+chain+is+only+as+strong+as+its+weakest+link.html), comme *Une chaîne n'est pas plus solide que ne l'est son maillon le plus faible.* Est-ce que c'est vraiment ce que le sfrançais disent pour communiquer cette idée?

Comment: On trouve aussi "Une chaîne est aussi forte que son maillon le plus faible," sur Internet. Mais je soupçonne que les deux versions sont des traductions de l'anglais

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'expression qui existe en français est "maillon faible" (et non *maillon le plus faible*)

> ex: être le maillon faible d'une équipe.

C'est aussi le nom d'un [jeu télévisé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Maillon_faible_(jeu_t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9)) assez connu (adaptation d'un jeu britannique)

De mon point de vue l'expression n'est pas très courante. Pour ce qui est de la phrase complète que tu cite, je ne l'ai jamais lue ou entendue, je penche donc pour une traduction.